# Search and replace words in a string with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace, str-replace

I have a string like this:

```
"This is a random string with @[certain] words with this format @[something]"
```

I want to replace that words wrapped by `@[]`

So my result has to be like this:

```
"This is a random string with words with the format"
```

I'm using PHP.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the attempts to solve the problem. See [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of regular expressions for the pattern and replace your string using `preg_replace`.

Something like this,

```
$str = "This is a random string with @[certain] words with this format @[something]";
$newStr = preg_replace('/\ @\[(\w+)\]/','',$str);
```

You can also write this in a single line,

```
echo preg_replace('/\ @\[(\w+)\]/','',"This is a random string with @[certain] words with this format @[something]");
```